# Дискорд бот не отправляет сообщение из блока @command.error

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

```
@bot.command()
@commands.has_role(983027842705133578)
async def whoami(ctx, name):
    await ctx.reply("Ваша роль " + str(ctx.message.author.top_role.mention))
@whoami.error
async def whoami_error(error, ctx):
    if isinstance(error, MissingPermissions):
        await ctx.send("You dont have permission")
```

Когда человек с нужной ролью вызывает команду то всё работает, но когда нужной роли нет, то ничего не происходит. Бот сообщение не отправляет, а в консоль ничего не выводится. Заранее спасибо.
Полный код - https://pastebin.com/raw/Q1Ahiy2X

Comment: А откуда вы взяли строку `bot.send_message`? Не увидел в документации ничего подобного

Comment: @denisnumb Пролистывал интернет и нашёл такое решение, исправил

Comment: Дело в том, что в интернете не всегда бывают правильные решения. Поэтому прежде чем задавать вопрос о том, почему же не работает код из интернета, стоит сначала разобраться в том, как он работает и **должен ли работать вообще**, сверив методы и свойства с документацией. Конкретно в вашем случае у объекта `bot` в списке методов нет даже ничего похожего на `send_message()`, потому что метод отправки сообщения вызывается у канала (`await ctx.channel.send(. . .)`)

Comment: @denisnumb Хорошо, в следующий учту, спасибо. Я кстати исправил, но сообщение не отправляется не через ctx.reply, не через ctx.channel.send, и не через ctx.send как предложили ниже

Comment: Попробуйте в конец `whoami_error` добавить строку, не зависящую от условия — `raise error`. Вызовите команду и посмотрите что за ошибка будет выведена в консоль. Если это не `MissingPermissions`, то проблема в том, что вы просто исключаете не ту ошибку

Comment: @denisnumb я стёр строчку с if впринципе, и всё заработало 0_О

Comment: Вы хоть поняли в чем проблема? Нет, она не в строчке `if isinstance(error, commands.MissingPermissions):`. Проблема в том, что вы исключали ошибку `MissingPermissions`, в то время, как ошибка была в другом. А сейчас вы любую ошибку в команде будете исключать как `MissingPermissions` и отправлять в чат *`"You dont have permission"`*, даже если  просто в коде команды будет какая-то опечатка

Comment: @denisnumb да, я понял. Нужно было ловить ошибку MissingRole

Comment: Отлично :)
Вот это уже можно писать в ответ и отмечать его как принятый

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я ловил не ту ошибку, нужно не MissingPermissions, a MissingRole

Comment: Предлагаю в таком случае закрыть данный вопрос, отметив этот ответ как верный :)

Answer (score 2):

1. Нужно заменить Missing.Permissions на commands.MissingRole
2. Впервые вижу такую отправку сообщения `await bot.send_message(ctx.message.channel, "you dont have permission")`, замените её на `await ctx.send("You dont have permission")`

```py
@whoami.error
async def whoami_error(error, ctx):
    if isinstance(error, commands.MissingRole):
        await ctx.send("You dont have permission")
```

Comment: Сделал как Вы сказали, бот всё-равно почему-то не отправляет сообщение